# block at require statement in PHP 5.5

Tags: php

I used to ran my website with PHP 5.3 and everything worked great. After upgrading to 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 (what *phpversion()* says), my facebook login script file gets blocked at the line:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';
```

either I write it like that as indicated in the [facebook documentation](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk), or like

```
require('facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php');
```

So, I cannot figure out what happens here and I think that it should be a PHP issue. Any clue?

**Note**. The facebook SDK that I use in the require statement is deprecated but it still runs with my PHP 5.3, but not with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7.

Comment: Turn errors on and see what output you get. Might be that some PHP functions were removed that the Facebook library depends on.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, it's as you said. Setting "display_errors = On" in the php.ini I could read a message and googling for that message I could solve my problem easily